# C++ Про идиому обнаружения, или изобретаем велосипед (concepts)

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

## Общая постановка задачи:

Имеется 100500+ классов, которые имеют примерно схожую реализацию (30% контейнеров, 30% итераторов, и остальные специфичные).

### Нужно:

Сделать общую реализацию **для каждого типа классов**.

### Пример:

Возьмем в качестве типа классов **класс-контейнер**.

```
template <class Ty>
class container{
  ...
}
```

Любой контейнер должен содержать:

**using-и**:

```
using value_type = Ty
```

**функции**:

```
begin()
end()
insert(const value_type&)
insert(value_type&&)
```

## Решение:

Для того, чтобы каждый класс контейнер имел одинаковую реализацию, чтобы имена всех функция и переменных совпадали, будем реализовывать класс-проверщик.

Его функция очень простая. Вызвать static_assert для каждой функции из перечня. Проделывать он это будет с каждым классом-контейнером.

В итоге мы будем получать ошибку на стадии компиляции о том, что класс не соответствует перечню неких требований. Например, вместо функции insert, реализована функция Insert (заглавная) или не реализована совсем.

### Шаг 1. **Реализуем прототип готового класса-контейнера:**

```
 template <class Ty>
    class container{
      using value_type = Ty;

      begin() {}
      end() {}
      insert(const value_type&) {}
      insert(value_type&&) {}
    } ;
```

### Шаг 2. Возьмем код с сайта [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) и добавим наш класс-контейнер.

```
namespace detail {
  template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
    template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
  struct detector {
    using value_t = std::false_type;
    using type = Default;
  };

  template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
  struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
    using value_t = std::true_type;
    using type = Op<Args...>;
  };

} // namespace detail

struct nonesuch {
  ~nonesuch()                     = delete;
  nonesuch(nonesuch const&)       = delete;
  void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

// Наш КЛАСС_КОНТЕЙНЕР
template <class Ty>
class container{
  using value_type = Ty;

  begin() {}
  end() {}
  insert(const value_type&) {}
  insert(value_type&&) {}
}

// Проверка на существование функции insert
template <class T>
using has_insert_t = decltype(.....); // То место, которое я не понимаю, как реализовать.

class container_check{
  static_assert(is_detected<has_insert_t, container>::value, "!");  // нужно проверить insert(const value_type&)
  static_assert(is_detected<has_insert_t, container>::value, "!");  // нужно проверить insert(value_type&&)
};
```

Это пример реализации экспериментальной(?) функции is_detect.

Как я понял, она реализует идеому обнаружения, которая, в свою очередь, реализует возможность обнаружить какую-то функцию в классе. Но что делать, если **в классе две перегруженные функции**, а нужно проверить наличие каждой?

### И вот вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я вообще понимаю эту идиому?
2. Как проверить наличие **всех перегруженных функций**, через эту идиому?
3. Или, если я всё-таки неправильно понял, что делает код обнаружения, подскажите, каким способом можно решить поставленную задачу.
4. И **главное**, какая должна быть реализация у **has_insert_t**, если проверяемая функция имеет аргументы или **несколько аргументов**.

P.s. За клавиатурой стажёр, так что следующий пример может вызвать у вас приступ паники (или 1001 ошибку компиляции), **будьте осторожны**.

Я так понимаю, что-то такое?

```
template <class Ty, class... Args>
using has_insert_t = decltype(::std::declval<Ty::insert>(Args...))
```

Comment: сюда бы concept...

Comment: Ну,  допустим написали , ну вот зачем он нужен?  Как он может работать с объектами конкретного класса?  Только чтобы проверить наличие метода? Если только в учебных целях...

Comment: Мне кажется, или вы изобрели вело... Ну, в смысле, концепты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Итак, вот моё решение

### Шаг 1. Сначала проверим, что в **классе-контейнере** есть using value_type = ...

```
template<class Ty, class Using = void>
class has_value_type final : public std::false_type {};

template<class Ty>
class has_value_type<Ty, STD void_t<typename Ty::value_type>> final : public std::true_type {};
```

Эта конструкция позволяет узнать, есть ли объявление **value_type** в каком-то классе. Используем это позже.

### Шаг 2. Теперь нужен код, который будет проверять функцию с конкретными параметрами.

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
using has_insert = decltype(std::declval<T>().insert(std::declval<Ts>()...));
```

### Шаг 3. Пишем класс-проверщк.

```
template <class Ty>
class CONTAINER_CHECK {
public:
  CONTAINER_CHECK() = delete; // Экземпляры класса не нужно создавать, запретим конструктор.

  static check() {
      // Проверим, есть ли в классе value_type и iterator
    static_assert(has_value_type<Ty>::value, "!");
    static_assert(has_iterator<Ty>::value, "!");

    using value_type = typename Ty::value_type;
    using iterator = typename Ty::iterator;

    // Проверяем, есть ли обе перегруженные функции.
    static_assert(is_detected<has_insert, Ty, iterator, value_type&&>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_detected<has_insert, Ty, iterator, const value_type&>::value, "!");
  }
};
```

## Для ленивых полное решение ;)

```
namespace detail {
  template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
    template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
  struct detector {
    using value_t = std::false_type;
    using type = Default;
  };

  template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
  struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
    using value_t = std::true_type;
    using type = Op<Args...>;
  };

} // namespace detail

struct nonesuch {
  ~nonesuch() = delete;
  nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
  void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

// Наш КЛАСС_КОНТЕЙНЕР
template <class Ty>
class container {
  using value_type = Ty;

  begin() {}
  end() {}
  insert(const value_type&) {}
  insert(value_type&&) {}
}

// Проверка на существование функции insert
template <class T, class... Ts>
using has_insert = decltype(std::declval<T>().insert(std::declval<Ts>()...));

template <class Ty>
class CONTAINER_CHECK {
public:
  CONTAINER_CHECK() = delete; // Экземпляры класса не нужно создавать, запретим конструктор.

  static check() {
      // Проверим, есть ли в классе value_type и iterator
    static_assert(has_value_type<Ty>::value, "!");
    static_assert(has_iterator<Ty>::value, "!");

    using value_type = typename Ty::value_type;
    using iterator = typename Ty::iterator;

    // Проверяем, есть ли обе перегруженные функции.
    static_assert(is_detected<has_insert, Ty, iterator, value_type&&>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_detected<has_insert, Ty, iterator, const value_type&>::value, "!");
  }
};

int main(){
  CONTAINER_CHECK<container>::check();
}
```

## Задача решена!

Answer (score 0):

## Отвечаю на ваши вопросы.

### Вопрос 1.

> Ну, допустим написали , ну вот зачем он нужен? Как он может работать с объектами конкретного класса? Только чтобы проверить наличие метода? Если только в учебных целях...

В написании проекта (точнее подпроекта, где я работаю) участвуют +- 10 программистов. Каждый из которых написал и напишет еще по десятку контейнеров (к примеру). Каждый из них называет переменную типа хранимых данных по-своему. Кто-то, кто хочет соответствовать стандарту, назовет её **value_type**, тот, кто любит сокращать - назовёт **value_t**, а кто совсем уж любит покороче - **vt**. В этот список также можно добавить **type_of_value**, **_valueType**, **ValueType** и еще много-много вариантов.

Теперь к сути. Любое отклонение от стандарта не позволяет написать единый код, который бы, к примеру, создавал переменную того же типа, что и данные, хранимые в контейнере.

Мы могли бы написать код:

```
using type = container::value_type;
```

Но вместо value_type в проекте каша из разных названий этой переменной во всех классах.

Мое решение позволяет вызвать статический метод, который проверит соответствие всех переменных и функций. Так как он работает в runtime и только один раз, на производительность это никаким образом не влияет.

Плюс к этому многие забывают объявлять нужные методы. Например реализовывают **begin()** и **end()**, а вот про **cbegin, rbegin, crbegin, cend, rend, crend** забывают. Это, опять же, усложняет задачу другим программистам, которые используют совмсетный код.

> p.s.Мы не будем говорить о том, что тип можно узнать, получив данные из
> контейнера и узнав их тип. Мы сейчас абстрагировались и решаем общую
> проблему, ведь случай может быть намного сложнее.

### Вопрос 2.

> Мне кажется, или вы изобрели вело... Ну, в смысле, концепты?

Так и получается. Я пока ещё не ведущий разработчик компании и не могу заставить его перевести проект на c++20. Но я обязательно им стану! :)